# email validation with text watcher

Tags: android

can anyone help me for the email validation in this code?
i tried much thing but it does'nt shows any response...
please help...
thank u.

**Code  :**

```
 etfeedbackemail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (etfeedbackemail.getText().toString() == "") {
                etfeedbackemail.setError("Please enter your email.");
            }
            if (etfeedbackemail.getText().toString().contains(".*[^a-z^0-9].*")) {
                etfeedbackemail.setError("Enter a valid address");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: ya i can accept it, its perfect thnx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

on your textWatcher

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
               if(!isValidEmail(etfeedbackemail.getText().toString())){
         etfeedbackemail.setError("Enter a valid address");

    }
            }
```

Check the email is valid on other method that returns boolean

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(String target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            //android Regex to check the email address Validation
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not working if email address is perfect then also it shows the validation...

Comment: make sure you gave '!' inside the  if(!isvalidEmail)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Androids email pattern. Here is code in Kotlin, you can do similar in JAVA

```
 etfeedbackemail.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            // Does nothing intentionally
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            // Does nothing intentionally
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            val email = s.toString()
            val isValid = android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
            if (!isValid) {
                etfeedbackemail.setError("Invalid Email")
            } else {
                etfeedbackemail.setError(null)
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code it works for me-

replace your line of code-

```
 `etfeedbackemail.setError("Please enter your email.");`
```

by these lines

```
 Drawable errorIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error_icon);
 etfeedbackemail.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='white'>"+errorMSG+"</font>"),errorIcon);
```

all the best..

Answer (score 0):

check this answer

```
  final EditText emailValidate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage); 

  final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 

  String email = emailValidate.getText().toString().trim();

   String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

  emailValidate .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 

if (email.matches(emailPattern) && s.length() > 0)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // or
        textView.setText("valid email");
    }
    else
    {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //or
        textView.setText("invalid email");
    }
} 
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
// other stuffs 
} 
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
// other stuffs 
} 
});
```